# .NET soap web service that returns JSON- how does it work?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I don't have something in particular that I need to implement, I am just trying to understand some concepts.

As far as I know, .NET web method (for example), that is inside a web service, is using the SOAP protocol. that means that the data received to the server needs to be in XML format, and the data that is returned from the web method should also be in XML format.

I know I can write something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Object someMethod(Object josn)
{
    Console.Write(json("someProperty"));
    return new {name = "John"}
}
```

I know that data sent back to the client is in JSON format...
but if we are using the SOAP protocol, shouldn't it return XML? 
I want to understand what is happening behind the scene or what am I missing, does the request was sent in xml format and the .NET framework knows how to extract the parameters that were sent, if so- how can I retrieve the full xml that represents the request made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is called the SOAP envelope. Take a look here:

[Sample SOAP Envelope](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_examples.htm)

One of the easiest ways to see the SOAP envelope that is being used in a request or response is to use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

**EDIT**

Here's an example of WCF SOAP envelope with JSON (not sure if you are using WCF or the old .NET Web Service with ASMX files):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header></s:Header>
  <s:Body>[{"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(286801200000+1300)\/","FirstName":"Foo","Id":1,"LastName":"Bar"},{"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(333720000000+1200)\/","FirstName":"Foo","Id":1,"LastName":"Bar"}]</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: So, when the web method is being called, the .NET framework knows how to parse this envelope and retrieve the parameter that was sent inside it?

Comment: @itay312 yes, whatever parameters were passed in the SOAP envelope will become available to you in code-behind.